# C# generic inputs and outputs

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, generics

New to gerics: 
I am trying to write a Add method to update database with different data contracts passed to it. need to know if it is ok to do as below:

```
enter code here
public static bool Add<T>(T data)
{
if (data.GetType().Name.Equals("Test"))
{
var memberData = (Test)Convert.ChangeType(data, (new Test()).GetType());
// Update member data
}
if (data.GetType().Name.Equals("Test1"))
{
 var someotherdata = (Test1)Convert.ChangeType(data, (new Test()).GetType());
 // Update someother data
}

//return true / false
        }
```

Comment: why don't you run it and see what happens?

Comment: its not a question to see if it works or not..and it works if i run it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generics are really for cases where you can apply the same general (i.e. *generic)* strategy to all types passed in. If you have to handle each type differently, this is really not a good candidate for generics. In this case I'd recommend simply having different overloads:

```
public static bool Add(Test data)
{
    // Update member data
    //return true / false
}

public static bool Add(Test1 data)
{
    // Update someother data
    //return true / false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use generics in this case. You could simply declare the parameter as `object`.

And `(new Test()).GetType()` is a bad idea. The correct way would be `typeof(Test)`.